# C# getting sorted list of images

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm trying to get a sorted list of images paths strings in a praticular directory.
The directory contains 43 images named by numbers: "1.png",  "2.png",and so on.

This is my code:

```
  var sorted = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.png").OrderBy(f => f);           
  foreach (string img in sorted) 
  {
   Console.WriteLine(img);
  }
```

The result i'm getting

> C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\1.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\10.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\11.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\12.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\13.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\14.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\15.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\16.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\17.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\18.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\19.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\2.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\20.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\21.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\22.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\23.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\24.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\25.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\26.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\27.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\28.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\29.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\3.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\30.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\31.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\32.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\33.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\34.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\35.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\36.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\37.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\38.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\39.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\4.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\40.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\41.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\42.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\43.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\5.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\6.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\7.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\8.png
>   C:\Users\itapi\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Draw\Draw\bin\Debug\9.png

For some reason I can't get a proper alphabetically order sorted list i tried also using LINQ `Sort()` method,with no success.

Looking for a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: That is alphabetically correct, it is not numerically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that it is a string so it is ordering by the rules for string sorting. What you want to do is to take the number part of it and order by it:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.png")
         .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(f.Split('.')[0]));
```

If not by using the `Split` you can use Scott's suggestion to use `GetFileNameWithoutExtension`:

```
Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*.png")
         .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)));
```

*Keep in mind that this is a naive solution that assumes that all the file names are `(number).png`. If it isn't the case you can first check if it is a number and then parse*

Comment: I would have used `.OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))); but pretty much exactly what I was about to post.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good suggestion :) like it, will update. Thanks